# Rename Gradle task

Tags: gradle

I have the desire to "wrap" the tasks generated by one of Gradle's plugins while retaining the name of the task that the users interact with.  It seems like the best way to do this would be to rename the task generated by the plugin and then create the wrapper task using the same name.

At first glance, TaskContainer#replace seemed like the way to go, except it just creates a new, empty task using the original name, while I already have the task object I want to put at that name.

How can I "rename" a Gradle task so that I can create a new task using the original name while preserving the original task?

Answer (score 7):

You could simply remove it from the task container while keeping a reference to it.

```
def oldTask = tasks.foo
tasks.remove(foo)
```

Comment: But how do I add the task back to the container under a different name?  I can do project.tasks.create('foo'), but that makes an empty task.

Comment: Change the task's name before adding it. `oldTask.name = 'bar'; tasks.add(oldTask)`.

Comment: Afaict, this is the best way to rename a task. Unfortunately, the name change is not reflected when running the `tasks` command (gradle 2.9).

Comment: Tasks cannot be removed anymore. Neither is possible to change their name.